# sns.countplot shows wrong value

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I try to learn tensorflow and Keras lately and I'm using matplotlib and seaborn for data visualisation.
I have a big set of data about house prices and elements like numbers of bedrooms. When I want to visualise the countplot for the 'bedrooms' column the function doesn't really work as expected.

For example let's say in df['bedrooms'] variable I store ~21000 different values that I want to plot using countplot. The only problem is that my chart looks like this:

[image]

I'm almost sure the expected graph should be different that this one, so I'm asking you guys what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need `sns.countplot(x=df['bedrooms'])` or `sns.countplot(data=df, x='bedrooms')`

Comment: Awesome, now I have the correct values, thanks !